# FInd the name of domain where programm runs

Tags: java, dns

Good day. I have a program which would work on different servers. The architecture every where is same. I have a storage to keep an images(e.g data/S0C00001/1/11/2014/08/282623142114856/log.htm). But the domains would be different. I need a code which would help  me to get the name of domain

Example
https://taras.plink/data/S0C00001/1/11/2014/08/282623142114856/log.htm
https://oside.plink/data/S0C00001/1/11/2014/08/282623142114856/b-img-000017.jpg

program should find where exactly it runs. (taras.plink / oside.plink);

Comment: I have tried next:
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress(); 
InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName();
InetAddress.getHostName();

nothing works correctly. When i try to start it on localhost those methods returned me name of computer user

Comment: The URI of the site is essentially impossible for the plain JVM to know for sure. You can probably ask the webserver for a guestimate but even then other infrastructure may do URI rewriting. Best solution? Use a config file. Of course if you know the architecture you can do other things.

Answer (score 0):

You can never know what the domain name is from inside the network. It's just like sitting inside a random house you cannot know what it's street is.

To get the domain name you would have to make a request to some other server who would see your program coming from a particular domain name/ip-address. It's just like you would have to get out of the house.

Make the other server send back the domain name it sees your program to be in.